# Unable to populate data array for VueJS Calendar plugin with dynamic Vuex store data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a Calendar Component in a VueJS app generated by the vue-sweet-calendar plugin.  The component renders properly using the static data, but when I comment that data out (as seen in the code below) and try to fill the array with real data, the array generated is empty.

Here is the component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="calendar-card">
    <!-- Using Component -->
    <calendar
      :eventCategories="eventCategories"
      :events="events"
      ref="calendar"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Importing Component and style
import { Calendar } from 'vue-sweet-calendar'
import 'vue-sweet-calendar/dist/SweetCalendar.css'
import ActsService from '@/services/ActsService'

export default {
  name: 'CalendarCard',
  data() {
    return {
      eventCategories: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Personal',
          textColor: 'white',
          backgroundColor: 'Blue'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Company-wide',
          textColor: 'white',
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
      ],
      events: [
        // SAMPLE Calendar data commented out
        // {
        //   title: 'Event 1',
        //   start: '2019-10-02',
        //   end: '2019-10-02',
        //   repeat: 'never',
        //   categoryId: 2
        // },
        // {
        //   title: 'Event 2',
        //   start: '2019-10-08',
        //   end: '2019-10-08',
        //   repeat: 'never',
        //   categoryId: 2
        // },
        // {
        //   title: 'Event 3',
        //   start: '2019-10-10',
        //   end: '2019-10-10',
        //   repeat: 'never',
        //   categoryId: 2
        // },
        // {
        //   title: 'Event 4',
        //   start: '2019-10-23',
        //   end: '2019-10-23',
        //   repeat: 'never',
        //   categoryId: 2
        // }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    userActs() {
      return this.$store.getters.userActs
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getUserActs");
    this.setEvents();
  },
  methods: {
    goToday() {
      this.$refs.calendar.goToday()
    },
    setEvents() {
      console.log('setting events using these userActs: ', this.$store.state.userActs)
      this.$store.state.userActs.forEach(function(item) {
        events.push({
          item: {
            title: item.deed,
            start: item.created_at,
            end: item.created_at,
            repeat: 'never',
            categoryId: 2
          }
        })
      })
      console.log('these are the calendar events', this.events);
    }
  },
  components: {
    Calendar // Registering Component
  }
}
</script>
```

In the Chrome Vue console, I can see state.userActs populated with 4 Act objects, however, `console.log(this.$store.state.userActs)` returns an array with 0 elements.

Comment: `events` is undefined within your `forEach` callback. This should be triggering a runtime error. Change it to an arrow function, ie `.forEach(item => {... })` and refer to `this.events`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the Chrome Vue console, I can see `state.userActs` populated with 4 Act objects, however, `console.log(this.$store.state.userActs)` returns an array with 0 elements.

This sounds like your Vuex store is populated / updated *after* your component is mounted.

I would suggest creating a computed property for `events` so that it automatically updates when new store data appears.

For example

```js
computed: {
  userActs() {
    return this.$store.getters.userActs
  },
  events() {
    return this.userActs.map(item => ({
      title: item.deed,
      start: item.created_at,
      end: item.created_at,
      repeat: 'never',
      categoryId: 2
    }))
  }
}
```

Also remove `events` from your `data`. You will no longer need a `setEvents()` method either.

Comment: Very helpful. TIL... Thanks!

Comment: also found this for anyone comparing forEach an map methods: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f